# Removing Hash tag on my URL

Tags: ajax, url

I've created an ajax site that uses id to get the specific page.
Sad part is the URL doesn't look good.

Sample URL: **mysite.com/index.php#contact**

Are there other ways to improve this URL?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't look good" ?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: how do you want to improve this URL ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't really mean the URL doesn't look good. We all know what's good and SEO friendly URL. This one seems not like that. I'm just looking for some enhancement.